# How to create matrix table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create dynamic matrix type data display  using java script, html, and jquery which is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FunvZ/47/).

```
var reservations = [
    {"date":"22-12-2013","MCHC":"22","Pulse rate":"75","weight":"50" },
    {"date":"11-12-2013","CBC":"5"},
    {"date":"11-12-2013","weight":"55"}
];
var tbody = $('#reservations tbody'),
    props = ["date", "MCHC", "CBC", "Pulse rate", "weight"];

$.each(reservations, function(i, reservation) {
  var tr = $('<tr>');
  $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
       $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
  });
  tbody.append(tr);
});
```

The problem is that the code is working properly but it does not display unique data based on date.
For example, as shown in the above link "date:11-12-2013" is repeated twice which I don't want. I want to display unique data.

My desired output is:
[image]

Comment: I wonder how this question got +4 without even a comment. I believe you just have to sort and re-assemble your array before the $.each(...) sequence.

Comment: OK, if your array is ALWAYS to be of this kind, meaning, there won't be doubled props within a 'reservation' element, just filter then join apart the date the rest of a 'reservation'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/FunvZ/49/)

```
var reservations = [
    {"date":"22-12-2013","MCHC":"22","Pulse rate":"75","weight":"50" },
    {"date":"11-12-2013","CBC":"5"},
    {"date":"11-12-2013","weight":"55"}
];
var tbody = $('#reservations tbody'),
    props = ["date", "MCHC", "CBC", "Pulse rate", "weight"];
$.each(reservations, function(i, reservation) {
  var trid = reservation["date"];
    if($("#"+trid).length <= 0) {
      var tr = $('<tr>').attr("id",trid);
      $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
        var tdid = prop.replace(/\s/g, '');
        $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).attr("id",tdid).appendTo(tr);  
      });
      tbody.append(tr);
    }
    else {
      $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
        var tdid = prop.replace(/\s/g, '');
          $("#"+trid).find("td#"+tdid).html(reservation[prop])
      });  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var reservations = [{
"date": "22-12-2013",
    "MCHC": "22",
    "Pulse rate": "75",
    "weight": "50"
}, {
"date": "11-12-2013",
    "CBC": "5"
}, {
 "date": "11-12-2013",
    "weight": "55"
}];
var tbody = $('#reservations tbody'),
props = ["date", "MCHC", "CBC", "Pulse rate", "weight"];
$.each(reservations, function (i, reservation) {
//get the date value of the reservation
var tr = $('td:contains("' + reservation.date +'")').closest('tr');
if (tr.length <= 0)
{
     tr = $('<tr>');
}
$.each(props, function (i, prop) {
    var td = tr.children('.' + prop);
    if (td.length <= 0)
    {            $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr).addClass(prop.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    } else 
    {
        td.html(reservation[prop]);
    }
});
tbody.append(tr);
});
```

While this is similar to the response you already have it looks at the fact that Jquery does not like to have multiple elements with the same ID which the previous answer did with the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to organize `reservations` before you start building the HTML.

You could do that by using a function like:

```
function uniqueReservation(reservations) {
  var results = [],
      cache = {}, 
      reservation,date;

  for (var i=0;i<reservations.length;i++) {
    reservation = reservations[i];
    date = reservation.date;

    if (!cache[date]) {
      cache[date] = {};
      results.push(cache[date]);
    } else {
        cache[date] = cache[date];
    }


    for (var k in reservation) {
        cache[date][k] = reservation[k];
    }
  }

  console.log('results',results);
  return results;
}


//before you pass reservations to $.each
reservations = uniqueReservation(reservations);
```

You could probably write this function a few different ways. However, the idea is the same - organize the data structure how you want it and then build up your HTML. Anyway, here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7PR/).

Answer (score 1):

What about trying the below approach with `Vanilla JS`, I tried to make it simple and clean to be easily understood from the no JQuery fans, though it is getting benefits from the answers above.

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('#reservations').querySelector('tbody');
var props = ["date", "MCHC", "CBC", "Pulse rate", "weight"];

var reservations = [
    {"date":"22-12-2013","MCHC":"22","Pulse rate":"75","weight":"50" },
    {"date":"11-12-2013","CBC":"5"},
    {"date":"11-12-2013","weight":"55"}
];

var cache = {},
    date;
reservations.forEach(function(reservation, rIndex){
    date = reservation['date'];
    if (!cache[date]) {
      cache[date] = 'yes';
      var tr = tbody.insertRow(rIndex);
      tr.id = 'id'+date;
      props.forEach(function(){tr.insertCell();})
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    } 
    var row = tbody.querySelector('#id'+date).rowIndex - 1;
    props.forEach(function(prop,pIndex){
       if(reservation[prop]) 
         tbody.rows[row].cells[pIndex].innerHTML=reservation[prop];
    })
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

```html
<table id="reservations" border="2px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date\Mesurment</th><th>MCHC</th><th>CBC</th><th>Pulse rate</th><th>weight</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

For those who read from database, most likely there will be no 2 lines with the same date, so simple they can use the below JS code:

```
reservations.forEach(function(reservation, rIndex){
      var row = tbody.insertRow(rIndex);
      props.forEach(function(prop,pIndex){
        row.insertCell();
        if(reservation[prop]) 
             tbody.rows[rIndex].cells[pIndex].innerHTML=reservation[prop];
    })
});
```