# inconstant IndexSizeError with Matrix table

Tags: javascript

I tried to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41575063/2441637) solution in my app, the data is extracted from MS SQL database, if the time is sorted in ASC it works perfectly, but if sorted in DESC bases, I get the `IndexSizeError` error, I read about this error in other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699875/2441637) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073317/uncaught-indexsizeerror-failed-to-execute-insertcell-on-htmltablerowelement) but could not find an answer.

Below is my code, appreciate to get it solved. thaks

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('#completions').querySelector('tbody');
var headers = ['Date', 'FFS', 'SHF', 'SF', 'SCRP'];
var cache = {};
var date;
var completions = [
   {'Date':'11','FFS':'3,207'},{'Date':'11','SF':'1,501'},{'Date':'10','SHF':'603'},
   {'Date':'10','FFS':'4,643'},{'Date':'9','FFS':'2,352'},{'Date':'9','SHF':'603'},
   {'Date':'8','FFS':'4,008'},{'Date':'8','SF':'754'},{'Date':'7','FFS':'798'},
   {'Date':'6','FFS':'3,955'},{'Date':'6','SCRP':'503'},{'Date':'6','SF':'1,501'},
   {'Date':'6','SHF':'603'},{'Date':'5','FFS':'3,146'},{'Date':'5','SF':'1,503'},
   {'Date':'4','FFS':'5,375'},{'Date':'4','SF':'751'},{'Date':'4','SHF':'1,206'},
   {'Date':'3','FFS':'2,295'},{'Date':'3','SF':'752'},{'Date':'2','FFS':'6,300'},
   {'Date':'2','SF':'1,503'},{'Date':'1','FFS':'2,250'},{'Date':'1','SF':'1,506'},
   {'Date':'0','FFS':'2,236'}
,]; 
  
completions.forEach(function(completion, rIndex){
        date = completion['Date'];
        if (!cache[date]) {
        cache[date] = 'yes';
        var tr = tbody.insertRow(rIndex);
            tr.id = 'id'+date;
            headers.forEach(function(){ tr.insertCell(); })
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
        } 
        var row = tbody.querySelector('#id'+date).rowIndex - 1;
        headers.forEach(function(header,pIndex){
                if(completion[header]) 
                     tbody.rows[row].cells[pIndex].innerHTML = completion[header];
        })
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; }
table, th, td { font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; border: 1px solid black; }
th, td { width: 200px;}
th { background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; }
tr:hover { background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; }
td { text-align: right; }
td:first-child { text-align: left; }
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
tr:hover {background-color: yellow; color: red;}

h1 { font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal;
     font-variant: normal; font-weight: 500; line-height: 26.4px; }
```

```html
<h1> Production Hourly Report</h1>
<table id='completions'>
   <caption>Production Orders Completion Per Hour</caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Production Hour</th><th>FFS</th><th>SHF</th><th>SF</th><th>Scrap</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I still did not understand what is happening, and why when i sort ASC everything goes fine, while issues started when doing DESC sorting, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15866688/2441637) answer helpful, so i changed my approach for inserting the row at the end of the table from:

```
var tr = tbody.insertRow(rIndex);
```

to:

```
var tr = tbody.insertRow(-1);
```

and got my results displayed properly.